# Parametrized linq select() expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

This won't work:

```
Func<DAL.Activity, DateTime> f = 
    activity => activity.S_vrijeme;

using (var ctx = new GMDB())
{
    var timestamp =
        ctx
            .Set<DAL.Activity>()
            .Select<T, DateTime>(f)
            .Max();

    return timestamp;
}
```

...and I don't know why.

Visual Studio outputs these errors, and I can't find how to fix them:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Func<GM.DAL.Activity,System.DateTime>' to 'System.Func<T,int,System.DateTime>'

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GM.DAL.Activity>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<T>'

'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GM.DAL.Activity>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' has some invalid arguments
```

*Oh, btw, ye-olde-Google-search gives me crap. It may be that I don't know how to search for this expression-based stuff, since I'm new to it.*

Comment: what is `_timestampExpression`?

Comment: whooops, sorry - a typo; I'll fix it...

Comment: what is `T` in your sample?

Comment: What is _timestampExpression? Is GMDB a DBContext?

Comment: @VladimirGondarev already fixed :-)

Comment: I knew I'm gonna screw this up. The answer is ok, but my question was stupid. Going to open another one when I get sober >:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are passing the wrong generic types here. This should work:

```
var timestamp = ctx.Set<DAL.Activity>().Select(f).Max();
```